# verify if dynamically added content exists with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a div dynamically populated with different forms (depending from users task).
I need to verify which form has been added (I have an ID list) and, if present, add a button after the form.

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="dynamic_head">content</div>
<form id="dymanic_form1">....form content....</form>
----- here I need the button -----
</div>
```

in jQuery I tried

```
function newbutton() {
var bottone_modifica = 'new button html';
var arr = ["dymanic_form1", "dymanic_form2", "dymanic_form4", "dymanic_form5", "dymanic_form9"];
$.each(arr, function(i, form_id) {
  if ($("#" + form_id).length != 0) {
    $("#" + form_id).after(bottone_modifica);
  }
});
}
```

and this function is called immediately after the function that generate the dynamic form.

I also tried to refer to the new element with:

```
$("#container #" + form_id)
```

instead of

```
$("#" + form_id)
```

but that doesn't work.

Comment: Could you please add working fiddle? not able to reproduce what you describe in question

Comment: Do you want id of the newly added form?

Comment: attach a class to the button and after then search the button by the class

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra is quite difficult to make a fiddle for this part, as the form in #container is changing and created by ajax call

Comment: @patilprashant6792 I'll try if I can use your code.

Comment: @jefissu it's not a problem to add the button, but understand if I have to add the button based on the form dynamically generated in ajax

Comment: Please add your complete code with dynamic generation of form

Comment: attach a class to the button. Eg: class='genbutton' for every button created, then search with $('.genbutton')

Answer (score 0):

I think this may answer you question

```
var newlyAddedFormId = $("#container").find("form")[0].id //// Check for condition if length > 0 ([0] written without checking the condition)

var IfIdContainsinArr = arr.filter(function(item){return(item == newlyAddedFormId)}).length > 0
```

You can use this newlyaddedformid to put the button

Please mark as answer if this makes you clear

Comment: it doesn't work as it newlyAddedFormId = $("#container").find("form")[0].id get the origin form and not the dynamically added form :(

Comment: Please add your completed jquery code. I believe your question is not clear.